# How do you organise your timeline clips in Premier Pro

Tags: premiere, editing

I would like your opinion or the way you organize your clips for this situation:

A few days ago I got raw footage around 6h in length, 1 camera. It was recording all the time without cutting files on angles or scene changes...

So my workflow for this situation is to drag all to the timeline (Premiere Pro) and watch it all on fast forward, clean up trash and leave what could go in the final video.
At this stage, I have around 30m of footage left, around 900 clips and the final video should be 8m.

Those 900 clips contain around 30 different topics (people, objects, details etc.)

So I have 30 groups on the timeline, each group around 30 clips, and blank space between them.
I would like to have some kind of folders with group names that I can easily access.
If I drag a group of edited clips to a new folder in Project it will contain full unedited clips.

So my usual way is to have all on one timeline, including the final video that I am creating and going back and forth looking for next A or B clip on this same timeline.

I am 100% sure there must be a smarter way to do this, where I have all clips group under same name (I do not use labels/color as they do not mean much If i need 30 different colors) so please advise.

Comment: Opinion-Based questions are generally not appropriate for this forum.

Comment: I would like to hear how others solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I start out with a single long sequence.

I make cuts wherever the good stuff is, and move it up one layer to identify it.

I duplicate the sequence, then label the old sequence as unedited, and the new sequence as "edits".

I delete all the unnecessary stuff on the lower layer, then duplicate again, and make a sequence with all the good stuff in a single sequence with all the gaps removed.

If I need to split things up thematically, I would duplicate and rename sequences down to whatever granularity makes sense.

Then I would start labelling, colouring and adding markers as appropriate.

Would be interested to hear how others do it.

Comment: feels like this is also relevant sadly https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29538/is-it-possible-to-search-all-markers-in-premiere